# Using SELECT from WHILE as value in html input PHP SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

I am a complete beginner, so please bear with me. This is just a test project I am putting together to try to teach myself some of the basics.

I know that a lot of my commands are outdated and/or susceptible to injection, but I'd rather stick with this for now (many reasons).

I just had a question about trying to use `SELECT` from `WHILE`, and figured that out and got it to echo the correct response on the page.

Now, how do I make it `echo` that as a value for an HTML text box? It won't work, and I've tried to look for typos but I don't know what I am doing, frankly.

I see that the `$studentid` and `$teacherinfo` show fine, I presume because they are normal variables. 
Can I somehow define two more variables for first name and last name further up in the page so that I do not need to include so much code in each input (and to keep it from being buggy)?

Here is my code for the page. The inputs will be hidden, but I have been making them text boxes for debugging purposes.

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect($serverName, $userName, $password) or die('Unable to connect to Database host' . mysql_error());
$dbselect = mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection) or die("Unable to select database:$dbname" . mysql_error());

$studentid = $_POST['student_id'];
$teacherinfo = $_POST['teacher'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `first_name` FROM `students` WHERE student_id = '$studentid'",$connection);
?>
</head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <form method="post" action="vote_post.php">
                <h1>Vote for Teacher of the Month</h1>
                <h4>(step 2 of 2)</h4>
                <h2>Confirm the Information Below</h2>
                <h5>Student id: <?php echo $studentid ?></br>
                    Student first name: <?php 
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                            echo $row['first_name'];
                        }
                    ?>
                    </br>
                    Voted for: <?php echo $teacherinfo ?>
                </h5>
                <input type="text" name="student_id" value="<?php echo $studentid; ?>"/></br>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo $row['first_name'];
                } ?>"/>
                </br>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo $row['last_name'];
                } ?>"/>
                </br>
                <input type="text" name="teacher" value="<?php echo $teacherinfo; ?>"/></br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Vote" class="inputbutton"/></br></br></br>
            </form>
```

Comment: For starters, your php code shouldn't be in the head, it should be either outside of html or inside of body. Now, you have a "problem" which consists of ~5 subproblems. You should try to solve each individually and combine then together, each subset has been solved numerous times before. And besides, it would make more sense to fetch the array once and store the values in variables that you can easily use when you need them. Start with, for example, just querying the database and see if you get any results, just that alone is enough for a single question but then again, it should be easy 2find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `while` because your query return only one student. You have to use `if` instead of `while`. If your query return many students you can use `while`. 
Try this code:

```
<?php
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
    Student first name: <?php echo $row['first_name'];?>
    </br>
    Voted for: <?php echo $teacherinfo ?></h5>
    <input type="text" name="student_id" value="<?php echo $studentid; ?>"/></br>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $row['first_name'];?>"/></br>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $row['last_name'];?>"/></br>
    <input type="text" name="teacher" value="<?php echo $teacherinfo; ?>"/></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Vote" class="inputbutton"/></br></br></br>
<?php            
    }
?>
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to build a code that will help you. Remember that you use `last_name`, but does not return the field in `SQL`.

```
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <form method="post" action="vote_post.php">
            <h1>Vote for Teacher of the Month</h1>
            <h4>(step 2 of 2)</h4>
            <h2>Confirm the Information Below</h2>
            <?php 
            $connection = mysql_connect($serverName, $userName, $password) or die('Unable to connect to Database host' . mysql_error());
            $dbselect = mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection) or die("Unable to select database:$dbname" . mysql_error());

            $studentid = $_POST['student_id'];
            $teacherinfo = $_POST['teacher'];

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT `first_name`,`last_name`,`student_id` FROM `students` WHERE student_id = $studentid",$connection);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   

                echo "<h5>Student id: $row['student_id'] </br>" . 
                     "Student first name: $row['first_name'] </br>" .
                     "Voted for: $teacherinfo </h5> " .
                     "<input type='text' name='student_id' value='$row[\'student_id\']' /></br>" .
                     "<input type='text' name='first_name' value='$row[\'first_name\']' /></br>" .
                     "<input type='text' name='last_name' value='$row[\'last_name\']' /></br>" .
                     "<input type='text' name='teacher' value='$teacherinfo' /></br>"
            }
            ?>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Vote" class="inputbutton"/></br></br></br>
        </form>
```

`WHILE` I left because I do not know if your query can return more than one record, despite appearing to be a key. If you do not need to check the response of the Ragnar.